# Fancytree: manually regenerate key to avoid duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, treeview, fancytree

In my application I have two instances of fancytree side by side with different contents. `tree1` cannot be modified in any way and only serves to have its nodes copied into `tree2` via drag & drop (the `dnd` extension).

In the `dragDrop:` event of `tree2` I have something akin to:

```
if(data.otherNode.tree === node.tree){ 
  data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
}
else{
  data.otherNode.copyTo(node, data.hitMode);
}
```

The issue is that when I use `copyTo()` the node's key is also copied, and if I copy the same node multiple times throughout `tree2` I inevitably end up with duplicate keys. I know fancytree is able to auto-assign non-duplicate keys (for instance if the source json for your tree has no key value) but I have no idea how to do that in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

`copyTo()` has a callback function that allows you to modify the new node. Try this:

```
if(data.otherNode.tree === node.tree){ 
  data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
}
else{
  data.otherNode.copyTo(node, data.hitMode, function(n){
      // Set your new key here!
      n.key = <NEW_KEY>;
    })
}
```

Comment: Or 'delete n.key', which would regenerate the key.

Comment: Setting 'n.key = null;' will generate a new key.